# JS innerHTML script parsing

Tags: javascript, html

Is it a specification that `element.innerHTML = '<script>alert()</script>';` does not get parsed, or behaviour varies between browsers? Can i rely on `innerHTML` to **not** get scripts parsed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML5 the behavior is specified to **not** execute inserted <script> elements, however as this page from Mozilla notes, there are still ways to get around this to execute javascript, so you can't rely on this for security.

HTML5 Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0

> script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations

> there is still a security risk whenever you use innerHTML to set strings over which you have no control. For example:
>
> ```
> const name = "<img src='x' onerror='alert(1)'>";
> el.innerHTML = name; // shows the alert
> ```
>
> For that reason, it is recommended that instead of innerHTML you use:
>
> - Element.SetHTML() to sanitize the text before it is inserted into the DOM.
> - Node.textContent when inserting plain text, as this inserts it as raw text rather than parsing it as HTML.